# How do I grab values from cells in a spreadsheet from a different docs

Tags: google-apps-script

so this is the code

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CmJ5M2zVbfGG769zK5frbFg9F9qGx7ut2m8dBjgxUeQ/edit#gid=0");
var sh = SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(newActiveSpreadsheet);
var rand = Math.random(0,99);
var rand1 = Math.random(0,1);

function QuoteGen() {


  var G = ss.getSheetByName('This').getRange(1,10).getValue();
  DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody().appendParagraph(G);
  var L = sh.getRange(1, 2);
   DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody().appendParagraph(L);





}
```

The intent is to grab values from random cells but I can't make it work, it only shows Range, space or does not exist on spreadsheet(or an equivalent)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Obviously, the container document is a Google Document.

```
function runOne() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById("1CmJ5M2zVbfGG769zK5frbFg9F9qGx7ut2m8dBjgxUeQ");
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName("This");
  var lr=sh.getLastRow();
  var lc=sh.getLastColumn();
  //Logger.log(lr);
  //Logger.log(lc);
  var row=Math.floor(Math.random()*(lr));
  row=(row==0)?row+1:row;
  var col=Math.floor(Math.random()*(lc));
  col=(col==0)?col+1:col;
  //Logger.log(row);
  //Logger.log(col);
  var G=sh.getRange(row,col).getValue();
  row=Math.floor(Math.random()*(lr+1));
  row=(row==0)?row+1:row;
  col=Math.floor(Math.random()*(lc+1));
  col=(col==0)?col+1:col;
  //Logger.log(row);
  //Logger.log(col);
  var L=sh.getRange(row,col).getValue();
  var body=DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  body.appendParagraph(G);
  body.appendParagraph(L);
}
```